# Retrieve objects by Date using Query-By-Example (QBE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, db4o

I have a class with an attribute DateCreated, which as you may suppose, stores the date & time in which the object was created and stored in the db4o database.

```
private DateTime dateCreated;
```

Is it possible to retrieve using QBE all items created one specific day?

The query always returns 0 results, which I believe is because the objects in the database also contain the time in which these were created. Therefore, when using the prototypical object for db4o to use as an example, I would need to specify the time besides the date.

Are there any workarounds for this? Using Native Queries or the SODA Query API maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are able to achieve this using Query-By-Example. but with Linq to db4o you are able to write simple query:

```
var objects = from DummyType item in dbsession
              where item.dateCreated >= DateTime.Parse("1.1.2014 00:00:00") &&
                    item.dateCreated <= DateTime.Parse("1.1.2014 23:59:59")
              select item;
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I will try this and let you know the outcome!